# Запятые при указании на источник сообщаемого

Tags: пунктуация

Вопрос про запятые.

*"В соответствии с проектом первое введение препарата...";*

*"Согласно пункту 2 Закона были приняты меры...";*

*"На основании ст.ст. 2 и 3 Закона внесены изменения..."*

В таких конструкциях, когда источником является НЕ лицо (например, документ), нужно ставить запятую? Или во всех случаях она является факультативной?
Разъясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Здесь](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-024.htm) Обороты с производными предлогами и предложными сочетаниями обязательно обособляются, если они располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым: разрыв их непосредственной связи и способствует выделению оборотов. 
То же при разрыве естественной связи управляющего и управляемого слов.
 В других позициях, особенно в малораспространенных предложениях, такие обороты не осложняют предложение особыми выделительными интонациями и могут не обособляться (без специального на то задания); ср.: ***Во избежание утечки газа отключен кран. - Отключен, во избежание утечки газа, кран; Он сделал это в силу привычки. - Он, в силу привычки, сделал это; Согласно приказу группа расформирована. - Группа, согласно приказу, расформирована; За отсутствием состава преступления дело прекращено. - Дело, за отсутствием состава преступления, прекращено.***

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Рада помочь.